# Change output Rect color in RecyclerView ItemDecoration - Android

Tags: android, rect, android-recyclerview

I have this method in ItemDecoration class for recyclerView -

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,   RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.left = space;
        outRect.right = space;
        outRect.bottom = space;

        // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
        if(parent.getChildPosition(view) == 0)
            outRect.top = space;
}
```

Is there any way to change the color of output outRect like redrawing it or something ?

Comment: @pskink how do i use onDraw method here. It would require rect size etc. right ?

Comment: what if `view.setBackground()`?

Comment: did you read ItemDecoration javadocs?

Comment: @anil view.setBackground() sets color only to items, not to offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at `ItemDecoration` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration?hl=fr).

2 main things to know :

- `getItemOffsets(...)` will allow you to determine the space between your items with provided rect in params.
- `onDraw(...)` will allow you to draw whatever you can in that space you set in `getItemOffsets(...)`. You can use a `Drawable` or simple provided `Canvas`, etc.

If it's still not clear enough, check [this article](https://medium.com/@nicolas.duponchel/custom-itemdecoration-3b244de437d9). I explain how to build your custom `ItemDecoration`